# How to map a JsonNode into a java object with Commercetools SphereJsonUtils.readObjects with nested objects?

Tags: nested, graphql, commercetools, jsonnode

I can’t seem to work out the nested objects from a Json response. Here is my code:

```java
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
    import com.google.gson.Gson;
    import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;
    import com.sun.xml.internal.org.jvnet.fastinfoset.stax.LowLevelFastInfosetStreamWriter;
    import io.sphere.sdk.categories.Category;
    import io.sphere.sdk.client.HttpRequestIntent;
    import io.sphere.sdk.client.JsonNodeSphereRequest;
    import io.sphere.sdk.client.SphereRequest;
    import io.sphere.sdk.http.HttpMethod;
    import io.sphere.sdk.http.HttpResponse;
    import io.sphere.sdk.json.SphereJsonUtils;
    import io.sphere.sdk.models.Base;
    import io.sphere.sdk.models.LocalizedString;
    import com.google.gson.Gson;

    import javax.annotation.Nullable;
    import java.lang.reflect.Type;
    import java.time.LocalDateTime;
    import java.util.*;


    public class EvaProduct {

        private String id;
        private LocalDateTime createdAt;
        private LocalDateTime lastModifiedAt;
        private LocalizedString name;
    //    private LocalizedString description;
    //    private Set<Category> categories;
    //    private Set<EvaVariant> veloVariants = new HashSet<>();


        @JsonCreator
        EvaProduct(@JsonProperty("id")  String id,
                   @JsonProperty("crdAt") LocalDateTime createdAt,
                   @JsonProperty("lastModifiedAt") LocalDateTime lastModifiedAt,
                   @JsonProperty("name") LocalizedString name ){

            this.id = id;
            this.createdAt = createdAt;
            this.lastModifiedAt = lastModifiedAt;
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public LocalDateTime getCreatedAt() { return createdAt; }

        public LocalDateTime getLastModifiedAt() {
            return lastModifiedAt;
        }

        public LocalizedString getName(){
            return name;
        }


        static SphereRequest<List<EvaProduct>> getAllEvaProducts(){
            return new GetAllEvaProducts();
        }


        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "EvaProduct {" +
                    "id='" + id + '\'' +
                    ", createdAt=" + createdAt +
                    ", lastModifiedAt=" + lastModifiedAt +
                    ", name=" + name +
                    '}';
        }

        private static class GetAllEvaProducts extends Base implements SphereRequest<List<EvaProduct>> {

            public static final int MAX = 2;


            @Nullable
            @Override
            public List<EvaProduct> deserialize(HttpResponse httpResponse) {

                final JsonNode rootJsonNode = SphereJsonUtils.parse(httpResponse.getResponseBody());

                final JsonNode results = rootJsonNode.get("data").get("products").get("results");

                List<EvaProduct> evaProducts = SphereJsonUtils.readObject(results, new TypeReference<List<EvaProduct>>() { });

                return evaProducts;
            }

            @Override
            public HttpRequestIntent httpRequestIntent() {
                final String queryString = String.format("query product {\n" +
                        "       products(limit: %d) {\n" +
                        "           results {\n" +
                        "               id\n" +
                        "               createdAt\n" +
                        "               lastModifiedAt\n" +
                        "               masterData{\n" +
                        "                   current{\n" +
                        "                   name(locale: \"en\")" +
                        "                   }\n" +
                        "               }\n" +
                        "           }\n" +
                        "       }\n" +
                        "   }", MAX);
                final String body =String.format(
                        "{\n" +
                                "   \"query\": \"%s\"" +
                                "}", queryString.replace("\n", "\\n").replace("\"", "\\\""));
                return HttpRequestIntent.of(HttpMethod.POST, "/graphql", body);
            }
        }

    }
```

And from the Controller:

```java
    import io.sphere.sdk.client.SphereClient;
    import io.sphere.sdk.client.SphereRequest;
    import org.slf4j.Logger;
    import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.concurrent.CompletionStage;
    import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

    import static handson.impl.ClientService.createSphereClient;
    import static handson.EvaVariant.requestOfSkusEvaProducts;
    import static handson.EvaProduct.getAllEvaProducts;


    public class ZEvaKnowsGraphQL {
        private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ZEvaKnowsGraphQL.class);

        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
            try (final SphereClient client = createSphereClient()) {

                SphereRequest<List<EvaProduct>> allEvaProducts = getAllEvaProducts();

                CompletionStage<List<EvaProduct>> listCompletionStage = client.execute((allEvaProducts));

                List<EvaProduct> evaProducts1 = listCompletionStage.toCompletableFuture().get();

                for(EvaProduct evaProduct: evaProducts1) {
                    System.out.println(evaProduct.toString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I managed to get a complete result from a GraphQL request, so the JsonNode results has all the right values. For example it looks like this:

```json
[{"id":"098834e3-e636-4186-91e5-30176ee3c261","createdAt":"2019-12-18T14:38:53.617Z","lastModifiedAt":"2019-12-18T14:38:53.617Z","masterData":{"current":{"name":"cookie-BlueWine"}}},{"id":"238135fb-3fa0-4f54-9e52-d70e5bd38b43","createdAt":"2019-12-18T14:38:53.631Z","lastModifiedAt":"2019-12-21T19:22:33.324Z","masterData":{"current":{"name":"cookie-RedWinerru"}}}]
```

However I can’t seem to get the nested name value into my Java objects. So evaProducts now looks like this:

```
EvaProduct {id='098834e3-e636-4186-91e5-30176ee3c261', createdAt=2019-12-18T14:38:53.617, lastModifiedAt=2019-12-18T14:38:53.617, name=null} EvaProduct {id='238135fb-3fa0-4f54-9e52-d70e5bd38b43', createdAt=2019-12-18T14:38:53.631, lastModifiedAt=2019-12-21T19:22:33.324, name=null}
```

So name is null. 
Can somebody give me a hint as to how solve this issue? How do I get the nested value into the right field?

Answer (score 0):

In your graphQL query you query for English translation with `name(locale: \"en\")"` so the result will be directly the String for English and can't be parsed as `LocalizedString` which is a kind of a Map of Strings per locale.

To fix this you need to change in your `EvaProduct` class the `name` field to String or just update your query for to get the object for all locales.

Answer (score 0):

Oll'right, so I figured out the answer somewhere. Yes @Schleichardt, also the LocalizedString needs to be changed into a String, thank you for this, but also: I need to add a field:
private final Map masterData;
It will get the masterdata from the response and then I can use this in the jsonCreator/constructor to extract the values for the name like this:
this.name = ((String)((Map)masterdata.get("current")).get("name"));
Et voila, it works!